# Can the mouse pointer be controlled independent of the touch location in Windows 8.1?

Tags: c#, wpf

There are times when I need the extra precision of a mouse pointer on a Win 8.1 tab, but do not have a mouse handy. Am trying to make a small WPF utility that gives me 4 buttons : "Up","Down","Left","Right" which move the mouse pixel by pixel in the specified direction

However, when I tap any of the buttons, the mouse is moved to the position where I tap, making this method useless.

Is there any alternate method where I can detect a touch on a button without having the mouse pointer move to that location?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this: (quick code, won't compile)

```
Override OnMouseMove(Args e)
{ 
    if(controls.bounds.contains(e.point)){return;}
    else { base(e);}
}
```

or something like that.  Where the Controls.bounds represent the area your controls are in.  This should prevent the system from handling the clicks when they are in that area.  I don't do touch-programming, mostly windows forms, but you should be able to adapt that idea to work.